# Create an associative array in php with dynamic key and value

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I want to create an associative array in php with dynamic key and also a dynamic value from a particular mysql table.

The table name is `monthly_salary` with a two column named `month` and `salary` respectively.

I get the data inside it:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM monthly_salary');
$sql2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM monthly_salary');
```

Then assigned and concatenated the collected data to `$mon` and `$sal`:

```
$mon = "";
$sal = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $mon .= $row['month'].", ";
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
    $sal .= $row['salary'].", ";
}
```

After that I've converted it to array and concatenate it until it became and associative array:

```
$monArray = array(substr(trim($mon), 0, -1));
$salArray = array(substr(trim($sal), 0, -1));
$key = "";
$keyWithVal = "";
foreach($monArray  as $k){
    $key .= $k." => ";
}
foreach($salArray  as $k){
    $keyWithVal .= $key.$k.",";
}

$associativeArray = array(substr(trim($keyWithVal), 0, -1));
```

My Problem is that when I've echo it the result is always like this
**3500=>Jan=>3500**:

```
foreach($associativeArray  as $k => $id){
    echo $k."=>".$id;
}
```

So how can I fix it and with the correct output **Jan=>3500**?

Comment: Why are you running the same SQL query twice?

Comment: What do you expect `array(substr(trim($mon), 0, -1))` to do?  All this does is convert the string to an array, which gives you an array with one element.  `array('1, 2, 3')` doesn't make an array of 3 elements, it makes an array on one element, the string `'1, 2, 3'`.  To turn a string into an array, use `explode`.  `$array = explode(', ', '1, 2, 3);`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are way over-complicating this problem.  This can be done simply, with fewer loops.

First, you only need to run the SQL once.  Second, build the array in the 1st loop.

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM monthly_salary');

$associativeArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   // Put the values into the array, no other variables needed
   $associativeArray[$row['month']] = $row['salary'];
}

foreach($associativeArray as $k => $id){
    echo $k."=>".$id;
}
```

Comment: To show the association, instead of using a loop, you could do

   echo "<pre>"; print_r($associativeArray);

Comment: @Strixy: True, I was just copying the code from the question.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you just do:

```
$associativeArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $associativeArray[$row['month']] = $row['salary'];
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the one provided by Rocket Hazmat?

Comment: None, we just posted at the same time.  He/she beat me to it.

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator: That's because I'm a ninja ^^

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me for creating associative array. array_push don't work on associative array but using unary operator does work:

```
$associativeArray += [$key => $value];
```